# Redesigining fat-client application as a distributed work-flow

Tags: windows, architecture, distributed

My company currently services their clients using a Windows-based fat-client app that has workflow processing embedded in it. Basically, the customer inserts a set of documents to the beginning of the workflow, the documents are processed through a number of workflow steps and then after a period of time the output is presented to the customer. We currently scale up for larger customers by installing the application on other machines and let the cluster of machines work on different document subsets. Not ideal but with minimal changes to the application it did allow us to easily scale up to our current level.

The problem we now face is that as our customers have provided us with larger document sets we find ourselves spending more than expected on machines, IT support, etc... So, we have started to think about re-architecting the platform to make it scaleable. A feature of our solution is that each document can be processed independently of one another. Also we have 10 workflow steps of which two of the steps take up about 90% of the processing time.

One idea we are mulling over is to add a workflow step field to the document schema to track which workflow step has been completed for the document. We can then throw the entire cluster of machines to work on a single document set. A single machine would not be responsible for sequentially processing a document through all workflow steps but queries the db for the next document/workflow step pair and perform that processing. Does this sound like a reasonable approach? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure what specific development environment you are working with, I have had to deal with some similar workflows where we have a varied number of source documents, various steps, etc. all with different performance characteristics.

Assuming you have a series of independent steps - i.e. Step A's work product is the input for Step B, and step B's product is the input for step C, etc. I would look at message queueing as a potential solution.

For example, all new documents are tossed into a queue.  One or more listener apps hit the queue and grab the next available document to perform step A.  As step A completes, a link to the output product and/or relevant data are tossed into another queue.  a separate listener app pulls from this second queue into step B, etc. until the final output product is created.

In this way, you use one queue for the holding area between each discreet step, and can scale up or down any individual process between the queues.

For example, we use this to go from some data transformations, through a rendering process, and out to a spooler.  The data is fast, the renderings are CPU bound, and the printing is I/O bound, but each individual step can be scaled out based on need.

You could (technically) use a DB for this - but a message queue and/or a service bus would likely serve you better.

Hopefully that points you in the right direction!

Comment: Bob - Thanks for the reply. What you have outlined is what I suggested initially.